# populating variables inside an invoke

Tags: powershell, citrix

I need the $localuser to get populated with the username of the user running the script, My co-worker gave me this but its not working. are there any other ideas out there?

```
 $user = whoami
 Invoke-command -Credential "mydomain\service.account" -Computer myserver -scriptblock {param([string]$LocalUser); Add-PSSnapin Citrix* ; Get-BrokerSession -max 10000 | Where-Object brokeringusername -eq  "mydomain\$($LocalUser)" |   Stop-BrokerSession} -ArgumentList $user




 t brokeringusername -eq  "mydomain\$($LocalUser)" | Stop-BrokerSession} -ArgumentList $user
```

I still get the same thing.** **I changed it to

```
$user = $Env:UserName
Invoke-command -Credential "mydomain\service.account" -Computer myserver -scriptblock {param([string]$LocalUser); Add-PSSnapin Citrix* ; Get-BrokerSession -max 10000 | Where-Objec
```

Comment: Possibly it isn't working because `whoami` output includes the domain name and then you add the domain name again.  Or what about using `$Env:UserName` ?

Comment: `$env:UserName` is definitely a better way to get the current logged-on user (who is presumably the one running the script). However, this does not include the domain, which you _may_ need when passing credentials. Is this a workgroup environment, or a domain environment, and if the latter, is it a domain user that is attempting to run the script? (And are group policy permissions set to permit powershell remoting for the user in question?)

Comment: Its a domain environment. and yes they have permissions.

Comment: *I still get the same thing.* - which is?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and replaced the piped invocation `Get-BrokerSession` with `Write-Host`:

```
$user = $Env:UserName
Invoke-command -scriptblock {param([string]$LocalUser); Add-PSSnapin Citrix* ; Write-Host "mydomain\$($LocalUser)"} -ArgumentList $user
```

The output is (correctly): `COMPUTER1\Administrator`. Note: you can just use `"mydomain\$LocalUser"` which yields the same result.

So I presume that your invocation has an error. I would suggest to verify your snapins are all loaded as expected and guard your execution with a `try/catch` block to get more error details.

Side question: are you really invoking your command with `-Credential "mydomain\service.account"` or did you write it just for illustration purposes? In order to correctly pass your credential to `Invoke-Command` you would have to write something like this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential;
Invoke-Command -Credential $cred ...
```